# Может ли в HTML5 у тега А быть псевдоэлемент :after (или :before)?

Tags: html, css

```
a { display: inline-block; verticla-align: middle; padding: 20px; }
a:before { content: ' '; height: 100%; width: 2px; background: red; }
a:after { content: ' '; height: 100%; width: 2px; background: black; }

<a href="#hello_anchor">Hello moto</a>
```

Собственно вопрос в теме...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему нет? Хороший такой тег с хорошими псевдо-элементами. Эти псевдо-элементы будут кликабельными как и сама ссылка.

У вас, вероятно, в css-свойствах проблемы и из-за этого вы не видите их. Псевдо-элементы же строчные, а вы им пытаетесь высоту присвоить, да еще и в процентах.

Возвращаясь к псевдо-элементам... тут нет ничего хитрого. В каком-то смысле это два обычных тега вроде span, которые добавляются внутрь. Перед контентом и после.

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="before"></span>
    link content
    <span class="after"></span>
</a>
```

Отсюда, кстати, понятно, почему не получается добавить псевдо-элементы к картинкам или инпутам.

Дальше делайте с ними все, что угодно. Напрмер абсолютно спозиционируйте перед и после ссылкой, добавив какой-то эффект. Если не получается с псевдо-элементами, попробуйте вот с такими span`ами, потом переделаете в псевдо-элементы. Главное не забывайте добавлять content: ''; Но никогда не делайте * { content: ''; }

Ну и лично от себя добавлю, что не очень люблю псевдо-элементы. HTML получается более прибранным, приятным для прогеров, но когда понадобится потом найти ошибку в этих псевдо-элементах, фиг найдешь. Как вот у вас: попробуйте ткнуть в файбаге в эти псевдо-элементы и посмотреть, что с ними не так. Или вообще найти что-то в чужем коде, в котором все убрано в псевдо-элементы.